# How to get the type name (as a string) of an unassigned member?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, types

How can I get the type (it's name as a string) of:

1) an unassigned member?

2) the current class (I mean the one in scope) when no instance is available and without using a shared method?

EDIT: Come to think of I, I'm starting to think 1) is impossible.

EDIT: 2) may in fact never occur as such. Actually I meant the parent class of a nested class when no instance of the parent class is available (but an unassigned variable is) and without using a shared method of the parent class

Comment: The current class in scope is `Me` in VB.Net. Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: There would be no instance, but I rephrased the question, plz see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have an instance then within a method you can call `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType`

**EDIT**

Okay, based on your edits it looks like you've got this:

```
Public Class ParentClass
    Public Class NestedClass

    End Class
End Class
```

I think this method will do what you want. Usually "null is null" and doesn't have a type. But the method below cheats (kind of) by forcing the compiler to infer the type through generics.

```
Public Shared Function GetParentClass(Of T)(ByVal obj As T) As String
    ''//Get the type passed in
    Dim ThisType = GetType(T)

    ''//Get the outer type
    Dim BaseType = ThisType.DeclaringType

    ''//Return the parent name
    Return BaseType.Name
End Function
```

Then you can call this like:

```
    Dim X As ParentClass.NestedClass = Nothing
    Dim PCName = GetParentClass(X)
    Console.WriteLine(PCName)
```

Answer (score -1):

If its the current class you can use

this.GetType();

You can also use typeof operator 
see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Do you have a null variable at least? `Dim Obj as MyCustomClass`

Comment: @chris Yes I have, is there anyway to get the type of this?